# Create mapped entity when you only have the id

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm not sure how to phrase the question title to be honest, if someone has a suggestion, please let me know.

My use case is this, I have an entity with an account property like so (this is cleaned up to avoid clutter):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report_line", schema = "public")
public class ReportLine extends BaseReportLine {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "report_id")
  private Report report;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
  private Account account;
}
```

But a DTO that only has an account id / different properties:

```
public class ImportLineDto {
  public String groupName;
  public Integer position;
  public Integer parentPosition;
  public String accountId;
  public String name;
  public BigDecimal amount;
  public List<ImportLineDto> lines = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I need to go through / flatten all lines so I can save it to a JPA repository, but there are 2 issues:

1. Is there a way to create the table line object using the accountId only, without having to look up the account for each line, as that will add a massive amount of unnecessary db calls.
2. What should I do with the 'lines' on each table object after flattening? Should I set them to null / empty list?
3. Is there a better way to do this? For once I can actually make changes to the code

Here is what I have so far:

```
  private void saveReport(ImportedResult result) {
    Report report = new Report();
    ...
    report.setLines(getReportLinesFromDtoLines(result.lineItems.lines));
    ReportRepository.saveAndFlush(report);
  }

  private List<ReportLine> getReportLinesFromDtoLines(ImportLineDto lines) {
    List<ImportLineDto> flatLines = flatMapRecursive(lines).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<ReportLine> reportLines = new ArrayList<>();

    for(ImportLineDto line: flatLines) {
      ReportLine reportLine = new ReportLine();
      reportLine.setItemText(line.name);
      reportLine.setAmount(line.amount);
      reportLine.setAccount(???);
      // how do I set the 'Account' property using the id only, without looking up each account?

      reportLines.add(reportLine);
    }

    return ReportLines;
  }

  public Stream<ImportLineDto> flatMapRecursive(ImportLineDto item) {
    if (item.lines == null) {
      return Stream.empty();
    }

    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(item), item.lines.stream()
        .flatMap(this::flatMapRecursive));
  }
```

**Follow up:**

Just to throw a wrench in there, what if the DTO accountId was not the actual "id" field in the table, but another custom field, I have another situation like that, would it even be possible? I still need the answer the the 1st question however with a standard id.

Comment: `reportLine.setAccount(???);` should be `reportLine.setAccount(lines.accountId);` right?

Comment: That's what I don't know, the table itself has Account for that field, so java wouldn't like me trying to set it to an id.

Comment: IDK if it's your case, but you can create a `ReportLine` class that does not have the relations, but only the fields, and treat it like a normal table (so you will have manually to set the fields with setters)

Answer (score 0):

you may use entityManager.getReference as explained [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/)

```
reportLine.setAccount(entityManager.getReference(Account.class, line.accountId));
```